# How to use UnityEngine.TextEditor class? No documentation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using **UnityEngine.TextEditor** in my game in order to create a gui text editor for clients.
I know the basics of this class, as I already have the editor working fine.

```
editor = (TextEditor)GUIUtility.GetStateObject(typeof(TextEditor), GUIUtility.keyboardControl);
```

However I want to expand its ability, by adding Undo, Redo, Select All, etc.
But I cannot find any documentation in the site. No UnityEngine.TextEditor in the docs. And I have no idea how to use **TextEditor.Undo()** or **TextEditor.UpdateScrollOffsetIfNeeded()**.
(I also found this page https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/de/class/UnityEngine/TextEditor but the links don't work.)

Comment: The links would have basically taken you to the method definition and the method definitions are anyway present at the bottom of the page that you can refer.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri Yes they would but they just lead me to the same page url plus a # at the end. And the examples are just decompiled source codes.

Comment: Unity engine is proprietary software anyway, hence lack of source code as well that you could have looked into. I agree that the links on the page do not work, but they would have taken you nowhere other than the same page even if they worked. The method definitions (which show what the various methods are, what arguments they take as input, and what their respective return type is) are all present on that page which you can refer and play around to see if it works according to your needs. Those definitions are self-explanatory.

Comment: Unfortunately it has no doc, but you can try to read and understand the source code: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/IMGUI/TextEditor.cs Seems that you have to SaveBackup() before Undo(), and it only save one step.